# Are the gcloud output formats (specifically, the JSON for each command) documented?

Tags: typescript, gcloud

I'm attempting to script the `gcloud` tool using a TypeScript-aware JavaScript environment ([SLIME](https://github.com/davidpcaldwell/slime)) via `gcloud`'s `--format json` formatting. The scripting integration works well, but for each command, I'd like to use TypeScript features to constrain the expected return types, and am weighing how and whether to do it. Right now, I'm having to manually examine the JSON output in order to determine what the properties emitted by a command are, what the values are -- what the shape of the output is.

1. But I hope I don't have to. Is there an existing TypeScript declaration file for the JSON values returned by the `gcloud` tool?
2. If I do have to, I hope I can generate the TypeScript declaration files. Is there any machine-readable definition of the shape of responses returned by the `gcloud` tool? I'm interested specifically in `--format json` if it matters, but I doubt it does. I suspect all the formats are generated from one canonical structure; the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/formats) suggests that these are called "resources," but I can't figure out where the resource formats, or even what resources are returned by each command, might be documented.
3. If the TypeScript declaration files can't be generated, is there any human-readable documentation that would specify the shape of JSON responses from the `gcloud` tool? Or is trial-and-error for each command the only way?

Comment: I would recommend trying to limit yourself to one question, since sometimes that can be a persnickety topic regarding questions on SO, but I can see they're all related so I'll do my best to answer them in these comments, and then tidy it up in an answer once you feel the subject has been fully explained. 1) Not on GCP's end, at least not publicly and to my knowledge. 2) `Resource` is kinda a generic term, if you look for it in GCP docs it can refer specifically to folders and iam-policies; there exists Protobufs, which might interest you. 3) Yes and no, I'll explain in the next comment

Comment: 3) I'm not sure whether or not declaration files can be generated, but I do believe that we have human-readable versions of the JSON responses from the gcloud tool, since the responses are the same as those from the API. This means that it exists, but you'd have to look into the related API for each response you might want to make, which is not ideal. In my experience the [JS SDK](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference) tends to be the easiest to navigate, though your experience may be different

Comment: If you read the release notes, you will find that the CLI changes a lot each week. What are you going to do when each version is released? There are new features added, some are fixed, sometimes a feature is removed. The JSON is documented, but you are looking at documenting thousands of API methods. Your goal is commendable, but not practical in the real world unless you have a team of people working on this. To get a feeling, try documenting the Compute Engine insert instance API and there are hundreds more just as complex.

Comment: @JohnHanley if that's true, my option 3 would be impossible, but that's why I proposed option 2 (and/or option 1) -- if, when each version was released, a script could be run that could re-generate and update the TypeScript, it'd both be helpful for forward development and helpful for catching potential regressions caused by breaking changes.

Comment: Google documents the underlying REST APIs, but often the CLI commands are multiple API calls. That is why I suggested that you work with one Compute Engine API to understand the complexity of your goal. If I were building a skyscraper I would first learn to hammer a few nails.

Answer (score 2):

`gcloud .... --log-http` will show you the underlying HTTP methods.

[APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) allows you to search through any API|service for HTTP methods. It documents the request and response types.

The SDKs that Google provides for every API|service include the language-specific implementations of the resources so you do not need to recreate these for languages that are supported. While JavaScript is supported, I'm unsure whether TypeScript is specifically.

The [Discovery](https://developers.google.com/discovery) document associated with most services and the more recent gRPC Protobuf definitions for many services *should* provide a way to get to TypeScript definitions too.

If you can, use the existing SDKs. I'll have a search for ways to get TypeScript definitions from these. If Google doesn't already provide these, it's a reasonably request that it do so.

Google provides multiple types of client libraries:

1. The original and Google-wide (every Google service) has so-called [API Client Libraries](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library). In Google's repro for the [JavaScript SDK for the API Client Libraries](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client), there's a reference to TypeScript [types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/gapi).
2. For Google Cloud (only), there are [Google Cloud Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/cloud-client-libraries). For JavaScript (Google uses Node.JS), there's a [comprehensive list](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node) of idiomatic (the main difference to the API Client Library equivalent) libraries that are available and there's an [issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node/issues/952) (I've not read it) on publishing TypeScript types for them.
3. Lastly (!?) Google increasingly publishes the underlying protocol buffer definitions of it services (see the somewhat confusingly-named [Google APIs](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis) repo). Google uses protobufs internally and protobufs are increasingly exposed either directly or through [gRPC Transcoding](https://google.aip.dev/127) with its APIs. I'm unsure how you would get to TypeScript types (either from the protos directly; or via the transcoding).

Comment: Thanks, I've used a lot of this stuff already, so I think the `--log-http` part is the key for me -- it didn't occur to me to try to tie the CLI back to the "ordinary" Google APIs (that I have much more experience using). I'll give it a shot!